# Deriving uniform cubic B-spline matrix

Tags: polynomials, curves, spline

The page 6 of [this paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/02-graphics/pdf-color/10-splines.pdf) says:

---

Condition 1: $p(0) = q(1)$

– Symmetry: $p(0) = q(1) = 1/6(\pi-2 + 4 \pi-1 + \pi)$

Condition 2: $p’(0) = q’(1)$

– Geometry: $p’(0) = q’(1) = 1/2 ((\pi – \pi-1) + (\pi-1 – \pi-2))
= 1/2 (\pi – \pi-2)$

---

...but I don't see what symmetry it's referring to and how it reached $1/6(\pi-2 + 4 \pi-1 + \pi)$ and $1/2 ((\pi – \pi-1) + (\pi-1 – \pi-2))$. Could someone explain that?

Answer (score 1):

The article you refer to goes too fast. It should not be able to reach the conclusion $p(0)=\frac{1}{6}(p_{i-2}+4p_{i-1}+p_i)$ simply from positional continuity and symmetry. This article http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~anima/408/Notes/Interpolation/UniformBSpline.htm provides a better explanation about how to derive the basis functions for uniform cubic B-spline. Open this article and scroll down to the section "Deriving the Weighting Functions". The weighting functions here mean the basis functions and you can rewrite them in matrix form to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for an insight, but the page 7 of this paper
http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~reckert/460/lect17_2010_BSpline-Curves_3D.pdf
seems to reach the same equation without using simultaneous equations. -> 

"Need another condition to get d
Choose the following condition:
Q (at t=ti) = (1/6) * (P i-3+ 4*P i-2+ P i-1)
– i.e., control point at ti (Pi-2) pulls 4 times as hard at t=ti as control points on either side of ti
Substitute in polynomial equation -->d = (1/6) * (P i-3+ 4*P i-2+ P i-1)"